# Iterate over a text and find the distance between predefined substrings

Tags: python, text

I decided I wanted to take a text and find how close some labels were in the text. Basically, the idea is to check if two persons are less than 14 words apart and if they are we say that they are related.

My naive implementation is working, but only if the person is a single word, because I iterate over words.

```
text = """At this moment Robert  who rises at seven and works before 
       breakfast   came in  He glanced at his wife  her cheek was 
       slightly flushed  he  patted it caressingly      What s the 
       matter  my dear   he asked      She objects to my doing nothing 
       and having red hair   said I  in an  injured tone      Oh  of 
       course he can t help his hair   admitted Rose      It generally 
       crops out once in a generation   said my brother   So does  the 
       nose  Rudolf has got them both I must premise that I am going  
       perforce  to rake up the  very scandal which my dear Lady 
       Burlesdon wishes forgotten--in the year  1733  George II  
       sitting then on the throne  peace reigning for  the moment  and 
       the King and the Prince of Wales being not yet at  loggerheads  
       there came on a visit to the English Court a certain  prince  
      who was afterwards known to history as Rudolf the Third of Ruritania"""
involved = ['Robert', 'Rose', 'Rudolf the Third', 
            'a Knight of the Garter', 'James', 'Lady Burlesdon']

# my naive implementation
ws = text.split()
l = len(ws)
    for wi,w in enumerate(ws):
        # Skip if the word is not a person
        if w not in involved:
            continue
        # Check next x words for any involved person
        x = 14
        for i in range(wi+1,wi+x):
            # Avoid list index error
            if i >= l:
                break
            # Skip if the word is not a person
            if ws[i] not in involved:
                continue
            # Print related
            print(ws[wi],ws[i])
```

Now I would like to upgrade this script to allow for multi-word names such as 'Lady Burlesdon'. I am not entirely sure what is the best way to proceed. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Treat each name as a list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first preprocess your text so that all the names in `text` are replaced with single-word ids. The ids would have to be strings that you would not expect to appear as other words in the text. As you preprocess the text, you could keep a mapping of ids to names to know which name corresponds to which id. This would allow to keep your current algorithm as is.